# Database structure for application with many to many relationships?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a web application to keep track of Foosball scores.  I have created the base schema for my project which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Organization(
  OrganizationID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Player(
  PlayerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Username NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  Password NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  LastName NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  Email NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  OrganizationID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organization(OrganizationID)
);

CREATE TABLE Team(
    TeamID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE TeamPlayerXRef(
    TeamID INT NOT NULL,
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TeamPlayerXRef PRIMARY KEY(TeamID, PlayerID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TeamPlayerXRef_TeamID 
        FOREIGN KEY(TeamID) REFERENCES Team(TeamID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TeamPlayerXRef_PlayerID 
        FOREIGN KEY(PlayerID) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Game(
    GameID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE GameTeamXRef(
    GameID INT NOT NULL,
    TeamID INT NOT NULL,
    Score INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_GameTeamXRef PRIMARY KEY(GameID, TeamID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_GameTeamXRef_GameID
        FOREIGN KEY(GameID) REFERENCES Game(GameID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_GameTeamXRef_TeamID 
        FOREIGN KEY(TeamID) REFERENCES Team(TeamID)
);

CREATE TABLE Match(
    MatchID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE MatchGameXRef(
    MatchID INT NOT NULL,
    GameID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MatchGameXRef PRIMARY KEY(MatchID, GameID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MatchGameXRef_MatchID
        FOREIGN KEY(MatchID) REFERENCES Match(MatchID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MatchGameXRef_GameID
        FOREIGN KEY(GameID) REFERENCES Game(GameID),
);
```

With this setup I am able to have a player be on multiple teams (doubles), or a team by themselves (singles).  A match can then have multiple games assigned to it which is useful in case the amount of games for a match changes based on organizations (best of 3, best of 5, best of x).

My question is: With Team, Game, and Match I need unique ID's that can be created so they can be used in their respective XRef tables, but I don't really have any more data besides just the IDs in those tables.  Is this the correct way of doing this?  Or is there a better way to get the unique IDs for those tables (create them on the fly through my application?) so that I don't have to have just a table with IDs?

Answer (score 2):

Your model is appropriately normalized, and enforces the proper RI.  I can appreciate that it seems "useless" to have a table for which the only purpose is to generate an ID, but this ID is integral to allowing you to enforce the proper RI.  We call it a "relational" database for a reason, it is supposed to show relationships.  You have correctly modeled your M:M relationships between Player/Team, Game/Team and Match/Game.  You would probably hear some web, or UI, developers telling you it's "easier" to generate GUIDs in the business layer, but your database RI will be the cost... don't turn to the dark side :)

Being a sports fan myself, I have tried to model a number of sports, "game" related scenarios.  I might recommend adding "opponent" columns on the Game/Team Xref.  In the design you have, you will have 2 rows per game, but think of the TeamId in this table as "THE" team, and then add an TeamId_Opponent to represent their opponent.  "Normalize until it hurts, and then denormalize until it works"... you might find this useful when querying.  You could also add OpponentScore for the same ease of use, and then derive Result as a persisted computer column.